# Is it possible to use d3.js without html by clear svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How can I import D3.js script directly in svg file?

I try this

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

but code using d3.select and other d3 functions in another script in the same file doesnt work, when I open svg file in browser

Comment: if you need to use a d3 generated svg somewhere else try using a chrome extension called "svg crowbar" which lets you donwload svgs from any html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed scripts in stand-alone SVG files, but the syntax is different from HTML.

For embedded scripts, the main difference is that you have to wrap your code in an XML "CDATA" block:

```
<script type="application/ecmascript"> 
    <![CDATA[ /*script goes here*/]]> 
</script>
```

For external scripts, you specify the url with `xlink:href`, not `src`:

```
<script type="application/ecmascript" xlink:href="sample.es"/>
```

The other difference, as you can see, is they way the type of script is specified.  However, the type specification is optional as ECMAScript (standard Javascript) is the default.

[Full specs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html)

[Link to their live example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/script/script01.svg)